# How to assign List<Bear> or List<Goat> to List<IAnimal>

Tags: c#, linq

I have an interface (`IAnimal`) which is implemented by two classes, Bear and Goat.

At runtime, I may end up with a List of Bears, Or Goats, but whichever it is they need to be assigned to property `IEnumerable<IAnimal>`

This works, as `IEnumerable` is co-variant.

However, I now need to remove items from `IEnumerable<IAnimal>` which of course does not work.

What do I need to do to be able to remove items?

Here is the working sample:

```
interface IAnimal {}
public class Bear : IAnimal {}
public class Goat : IAnimal {}

class Program
{
    public static IEnumerable<IAnimal> CouldBeBearsOrGoats { get; set; } 
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        var list = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3};

        var bears = from l in list select new Bear();

        var goats = from l in list select new Goat();

        CouldBeBearsOrGoats = bears;

        CouldBeBearsOrGoats = goats;

        //How do I now remove an item?


    }
}
```

If I change CouldBeBearsOrGoats to a List, then I can remove items, but I can no longer assign either type.

```
public static List<IAnimal> CouldBeBearsOrGoats { get; set; }
```

The list is going to be very long, and so I do not want to just make a copy of the list and work with a copy.  What I am doing is processing each item in the list and then removing it until the list is empty.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, a `List<Bear>` is not an `ICollection<IAnimal>`, so it doesn't solve anything

Comment: By providing a `List<IAnimal>`, you allow users to add a goat to a list of bears, which may not be valid in your system. If you only want to allow removing, maybe you should provide something like `IEnumerable<IAnimal> Animals { get { return _animals.AsReadOnly(); } }` and `void RemoveAnimal(IAnimal animal) { _animals.Remove(animal); }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your source data is anyway IEnumerable, you have to convert it to List to add/remove elements.

```
    List<IAnimal> ListOfAnimals1 = bears.Cast<IAnimal>().ToList();
    List<IAnimal> ListOfAnimals2 = goats.Cast<IAnimal>().ToList();
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted; it's actually a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

A posibility is to add a `Cast` call in your LINQ query, so that it converts the `IEnumerable<Goat>` to an `IEnumerable<IAnimal>` (which actually creates a new iterator with each element casted).

```
var bears = (from l in list select new Bear()).Cast<IAnimal>().ToList();

var goats = (from l in list select new Goat()).Cast<IAnimal>().ToList();
```

Now both `bears` and `goats` are enumerables of `IAnimal` which you can operate on them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an easy way to do that using only strongly typed collections<sup>1</sup>, since there is no covariant collection interface that exposes a `Remove` method...

I see 2 possible solutions:

- use the non-generic `ICollection` interface, that is implemented by `List<T>`:

  ```
  var collection = (ICollection) CouldBeBearsOrGoats;
  collection.Remove(whatever);
  ```

  The drawback is that a collection that implements `ICollection<T>` might not implement `ICollection`...
- use dynamic:

  ```
  dynamic collection = CouldBeBearsOrGoats
  collection.Remove(whatever);
  ```

  But it's probably slower than the previous approach.

---

<sup>1</sup> assuming you don't want to change the actual type of the collections by casting items to `IAnimal`